# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Ошибка возникает в `delete parentItem.items[sqlId]`

```
vehicle.inventory.updatePos = (sqlId, parentSqlId, index, callback) => {
        if (!parentSqlId) parentSqlId = -1;
        var item = vehicle.inventory.getItem(sqlId);
        if (!item) {
            if (vehicle.bootPlayerId != null) {
                var player = mp.players.at(vehicle.bootPlayerId);
                if (player) player.call("inventory.vehDelete", [sqlId]);
            }
            return callback('Предмет не найден!');
        }
        var parentItem = vehicle.inventory.getItem(item.parentId);

        DB.Handle.query("UPDATE inventory_vehicles SET parentId=?,`index`=? WHERE id=?", [parentSqlId, index, sqlId]);
        // if (item.parentId != parentSqlId) {
        //     if (!parentSqlId || parentSqlId == -1) vehicle.body.updateView(item.itemId, item.params);
        //     else vehicle.body.updateView(item.itemId, null);
        // }

        if (parentSqlId == -1 || !parentSqlId) {
            if (parentItem) delete parentItem.items[sqlId]; // тут
            vehicle.inventory.items[sqlId] = item;
        } else {
            if (item.parentId != parentSqlId) {
                if (parentItem) delete parentItem.items[sqlId];
                var newParentItem = vehicle.inventory.getItem(parentSqlId);
                newParentItem.items[sqlId] = item;
                if (!item.parentId || item.parentId == -1) delete vehicle.inventory.items[sqlId];
            }
        }

        item.parentId = parentSqlId;
        if (item.parentId == -1 || !item.parentId) delete item.parentId;
        item.index = index;
    };
```

Comment: Добавьте более полное описание проблемы, чтобы читателю было понятно, какая именно ошибка у вас возникает и что вы хотели сделать (это тоже в некоторых случаях может помочь)

Comment: У Вас в `parentItem` нет свойства `items` (а проверки на это у Вас тоже нет никакой). Или Вы проверяете `if (parentItem)`, но js иногда может выдавать приколы с тем, что объект как бы пустой, но `true` — помогает `Object.keys(parentItem).length > 0`

Comment: Какая схема у объекта возвращаемого методом `vehicle.inventory.getItem`?